# How to create a dynamic hierarchical charts using flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts, adobe

i am developing a tool to create dynamic hierarchical charts.. am able to create object i.e circles and link it dynamically. i want to set properties for those objects.. can someone tell how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this yourself, or are you open to a 3rd party tool?  We use [am Charts](http://www.amcharts.com/) which has a flexible API for feeding data to the flash components.  If you don't mind a small link in the chart back to the am Charts web site you can use all the charts for free.